# Trying to flash Gapps on Sony Xperia 10 III AOSP android 12

Tags: sony-xperia, android-12, aosp, gapps

I have a Sony Xperia 10 III open device and I have build an AOSP android 12 and flashed the build to the phone which has booted successfully. Since the AOSP is not having any google apps prebuilt, I tried flashing the Gapps through ADB sideload by downloading the .zip file of the Gappa from NikGapps, BiTGapps etc. While trying to flash the .zip file from the ADB in recovery mode, the flashing was not successful and the following error occured:

I have a Sony Xperia 10 III open device and I have build an AOSP android 12 and flashed the build to the phone which has booted successfully. Since the AOSP is not having any google apps prebuilt, I tried flashing the Gapps through ADB sideload by downloading the .zip file of the Gappa from NikGapps, BiTGapps etc. While trying to flash the .zip file from the ADB in recovery mode, the flashing was not successful and the following error occured:

```
E : Failed to find META-INF/com/android/metadata 
E : Failed to parse metadata in the zip file.
```

It was found that the directory tree of the downloaded .zip file was META-INF/com/google/android/metadata, but the search was done in the tree mentioned in the first error. I pulled the 'android' directory outside the 'google' directory. After this change, there is a signature verification error that arose

```
E: footer is wrong
E: Signature verification failed
E: error: 21
```

Since the recovery is stock, there is no option to disable signature verification. I am also unable to flash third party recoveries like TWRP and ClockWorkMod on Sony Xperia 10 III.

Is there any other method where we can flash Gapps to Sony Xperia 10 III? Kindly reply.

Comment: Not sure if it may help, but AFAIK custom ROM (e.g. [LineageOS](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/kirin/install#installing-lineageos-from-recovery)) recommends to flash GApps before the first boot: "***NOTE**: If you want the Google Apps add-on on your device, you must follow this step **before** booting into LineageOS for the first time!*"

Comment: If your device is unlocked you can boot any recovery ROM you want, so why keep stock recovers?

Comment: I don't find any third party recoveries for Sony Xperia 10 iii. I tried flashing some TWRP recovery images but it only crashed.